Changing embedded text in Notepad++
Good morning. I have a situation where I need to replace a keyword that may be anywhere on a line. The catch is that I need to add a comment line above. If the keyword is at the start of the line, I can do:
OldKeyword stuff stuff stuff
Replace: \nOldKeyword With: \nhashtag Comments\nNewKeyword
with extended search enabled. But if it's embedded, I need to take:
stuff stuff stuff OldKeyword stuff stuff stuff
And turn it into:
hashtag Comments
stuff stuff stuff NewKeyword stuff stuff stuff
retaining the code before the keyword.
Any help is Greatly appreciated.
I tried \n asterisk OldKeyword With: \n hashtag Comments\n asterisk NewKeyword
But it's as if that would be both extended and regular expression simultaneously.

You could use a capture group matching 0+ times any character except a newline, and then use that group in the replacement.
Instead of starting the match with a newline, you can use an anchor to also match the first line.
^(.*?)OldKeyword

In the replacement use:
hashtag Comments\n$1NewKeyword

See the replacement in the regex 101 demo



Nice link to regex 101. I did not know that

Very helpful. Thanks for your assistance !
